# Xamarin Studio XAML Previewer for Xamarin.Forms using Windows

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm using Windows and downloaded Xamarin Studio to build Xamarin Forms app. I saw that there is a [XAML Previewer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/) available if i update Xamarin studio using Alpha channel. So I updated everything using this alpha channel as described in documentation, but the XAML Previewer is not apearing on my Xamarin Studio. Some blog posts explain how to do this, but I saw that they are using Mac's. Is XAML Previewer available only when using Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got Xamarin Studio for Windows but it was discontinued when Microsoft took over since they want you to use Visual Studio.

Therefore the XAML preview is only available on Mac. It will be available for Visual Studio at some point but as far as I know there is no timeline for that.

There are however some alternatives:

- [Gorilla Player](http://www.gorillaplayer.com/)
- [XenForms](https://www.xenforms.com/)
- [Xamarin Forms Player](https://github.com/MobileEssentials/FormsPlayer)

Comment: I've got it from here. http://www.monodevelop.com/download/ . I'm using Gorilla Player for now, thanx.

Comment: MonoDevelop is even pre-Xamarin, Xamarin Studio is the offspring of that but I think it isn't maintained for a while now. Anyhow, it's not anymore for Windows and doesn't have the XAML previewer.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis FYI: Xamarin Studio is a superset of MonoDevelop and MonoDevelop is alive and well and still being maintained by Xamarin and the OSS community around it

Comment: @SushiHangover I see! However, last update has been 7 months ago, around the time Microsoft took over. And with the whole .NET core going cross platform and everything I'm not sure it it will be around very much longer.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis There has been over 2000 commits to MonoDevelop in the last 6 months, it is the base of Xamarin Studio and thus it is constantly been worked on... The last release was a few days ago: 2016-08-30  (tag: monodevelop-6.1.0.5383

Answer (score 0):

The XAML preview pane is shown automatically when viewing XAML for editing. The preview pane can be shown or hidden by pressing the Preview button in the top-right corner of the document window.

Comment: which version are you using

Comment: There is no "Preview button" in the top-right corner. Have you tried using XAML Previewer on Windows machine? I'm using Version 6.1 (build 5383) and my Xamarin Studio is Community edition.

Comment: confirm whether visual studio or xamarin studio and version?

Comment: I believe @khakishoiab meant for the OSX version... the "preview" function is not available on Version 6.1 (build 5383) and my Xamarin Studio on Windows.. :-( As you can see here https://youtu.be/98F6zjMJXX4?t=9m41s

Comment: Yes bro they have discontinued the support after version 6,but it may come up in any further versions.:(